# Does this statement means that we cannot show existence of non tight probability measure on a complete metric space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, logic, metric-spaces

In [Noncompact Simplexes in Banach  Spaces
with the Radon-Nikodpm Property, RICHARD D. BOURGIN](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123600X03199/1-s2.0-0022123676900732/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEC8aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDqP5H4YmH0qb5xSY%2BKtE7RPYq9ixpNroDcIZxZsGaOfAiEAupZMRz%2FrrZofJf58lM0zneO0EdwAsx%2BnL44fynuIOYcq2wQI5%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOuclIoy6V8%2F5DyIjCqvBOvvIeAQ09ib7DMLopVxPwQsi4pVCK8YkOeKo4LIOSiW6rD4e33c3WI3psdWuoFDtLx8xuXXKPihIkls%2BQb%2FS6J3cAOurGsuWbTEWIfEdG866UlpVzyKYfYsUKzGAPw28olzKNQVxaUfgHVAbAV550%2BXG9Fx2SmFxfTM1apxKft2FBL6LBIhiTM%2BGj121tQ%2F77kXI1vYGfV5WDayAGXO5F7SJh8r7S%2BzI0LOqb5ptCeCpMMHArCJfS%2B93zEYCnT7epVcDNyN90r8Ed6LbCzjwuJUDqDEE3ctmv78aDAVouFFo029qFhju8G8xNzGi%2BCqSuPNdg78yeRvXBJDoarpLG3nkq1EfdK6QXsGxe9VqANlEB6W6K4Xnc5hAqVFXTcEAbBX4Zm%2F6n6sZeLKqUxn5XGq5Rqj4JidVkgFjRXdW6lAp91%2FkgrlNRv3kqApgcYN9NF1QB7jXHl63DYybZRCAr%2BwJQgUQg0O%2FMEx3zUAY%2BfIifnWT69hwBTpsjK5CdjFG%2BIWNviH2DGcAH0TnrgW%2BbpqZtF%2FnRe6VhjqFII1WIwimJ4kcXxUqzRE1fqac4UKR8kkzbGXN1yt8wP3BYl%2BhuvSu8XIR%2Bp39bKQeNiEnrD0bKEpfGOkgF16e3Z3Ofbi2LI4b4AqBMi3Olm2OIDH2Khcemh6yn4A01nahM5DU9tQJ9%2BQwWvLnHqOT79NjH9ND5%2FG6o%2FNsdBFDBY9Swc6gTiaplv%2Bf15ka7mBZUOkcqswm4SukwY6qQHHVcZmGAL42bPQKaXXdglZnfpQBKz%2BFxzQ53gIh0k3K41kRojhGodcQSQNWtvYHddx9x9PdKaqpmqP7Jab6zgVGlHP6JqwwFIuFrw6I5ARMGiGpUoX8ZcA%2Bgg4VjdSvwoocR9ofrCi2hjgCBZpSPopEC03ic6ANqcjxGTfavtUe8%2FcCnJy%2BNw9I2oT4jZqujYOfEpGqGRE0r2NC%2F10gILHtG8XDb0LcREd&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220429T064747Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYU2X2XLG5%2F20220429%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=18ba9e51eae9f4e0873d140092951d9d245b805fabe02c7306dc0b82070bd865&hash=afa878b157816f7e7ddf5f46bcbc2b0a1a0b1bfcdadac3d5634e70df008241fd&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022123676900732&tid=spdf-55ed72ab-1f24-4b1e-8ca4-435c5040347c&sid=317858942c97344c9c-8bcf-e24ae919fa12gxrqb&type=client&ua=4d5451555f5357545508&rr=703616976f063b64), in Notation 2.8, the author states

> [...] It  is consistent  with  the  Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms,  including the  axiom
> of choice,  to  assume that  each probability measure on $X$  ($X$  a complete
> metric space) is  tight [...].

Does this means that ZFC cannot show the statement "there is a probability measure on $X$ that is not tight" ? What kind of "danger" is there in assuming that all probability measures on $X$ are tight ?

Answer (score 0):

It holds the following:

**Theorem:** *a family of probability measure on a Polish space $(X,d)$ is relatively sequentially compact if and only if it is uniformly tight.*

In the proof the usage of the axiom choice is every where. For example you need it (in a weaker form) for proving that the theorem holds in the case $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Finally you can use the theorem to observe that a measure $\mu$ on a Polish space $(X,d)$ is tight. You have to read it in this way: if we assume axiom choice in ZF, then we can prove a theorem that guarantees the tightness of every probability on a Polish space.

Comment: Well this I understand, here the statement is about non-necessarily separable spaces.